# How to make a drop-down selector?

Tags: gui-construction, menu

How to make a drop-down selector UI component?  Something that looks like [this](http://www.free-training-tutorial.com/dropDownList-example.jpg)

Answer (score 5):

You want to use [`PopupMenu`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PopupMenu.html):

```
PopupMenu[a, {a, b, c, d}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note, if you want it to be dynamically linked to a variable, use:

```
PopupMenu[Dynamic[x], {a, b, c, d}]
```

Then, `x` takes the value given by the drop down menu:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I don't need to show anything such as a plot that depends on the value selected in the drop-down.  Rather, I just need a state-recorder that knowns the user's selection in the menu which can later be read out from the notebook.

Comment: @MaThEmAtika See my last update.